# MahApps Dialog overriding Button style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm using the MahApps metro toolkit, and have the following inside my `Apps.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    ...
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
    ...
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Which nicely overrides the MahApps metro style for `Button` back to 'default'.

However, I've written a custom dialog (called DialogEditGroup - which derives from `CustomDialog`), but weirdly the `<Button />` style has reverted back to using some form of styling from the MahApps metro toolkit.

The only way I've been able to reset it again, is by adding the following lower down in my `Apps.xaml` `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:DialogEditGroup}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I really don't want to have to add this in for every custom dialog I write, and I'm sure the above 'fix' isn't the correct way of solving the problem. Can anyone suggest a proper way of addressing this issue?

[image]
`

(Top of image is 'mahapps', bottom is 'default / generic')

Comment: If you're not planning on using their style at all I'm pretty sure you could just comment out the `ResourceDictionary` import for FlatButton.xaml and ditch all inheritance all together.

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried that - it seems to force-add its own `ResourceDictionary` to anything derived from `CustomDialog`